# I don't have .htaccess file for my magento installation. How to get .htaccess file to remove the "index.php" from URL

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I don't have my .htaccess file for my magento installation which is by default present for all the fresh magento installation.

Now I have to remove "index.php" from my wesite url and found out htaccess file needs to be edited. But, there is no .htaccess file in my magento root folder.

Also, I have made a lot of changes to the website and don't want to do a fresh installation to get the .htaccess file.

Also, when I access my admin panel it also needs "index.php" in the URL.

Please, can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the inde.php from the URL you need to enable Web Server Rewrites.

You can enable Web Server Rewrites suing below steps:

1. Login in Backend, from Top Navigation click on `System` >> `Configuration` >> `Web`
2. Select `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `YES` in `Search Engines Optimization` group.

If you need .htaccess file, you can donwload the compatible magento zip file and can use its .htaccess. There is no need to install magento for this.

Comment: So, will the new .htaccess file break anything on my website?

Comment: No it will not break your website as per my knowledge

Comment: Why don't you simply download your magento version from magento.com and get the htaccess file from the package?

Comment: I have now enabled Use Web Server Rewrites to YES and now when i am accessing a footer link "About Us" then it's saying 404: File Not Found.

Comment: What is your magento version ?

Comment: you can download the .htaccess file from here: http://wikisend.com/download/580872/.htaccess